# Why do Plotly / Dash mixed graph and table subplots break when hline or vline are added?

Tags: python, python-3.x, plotly, plotly-dash

This is a 5 x 3 subplot layout as follows:

```
    fig = make_subplots(rows=5, cols=3,
                        specs=[[{'secondary_y': True}, {'secondary_y': False}, {'type': 'table'}],
                               [{'secondary_y': False}, {'secondary_y': False}, {'secondary_y': False}],
                               [{'secondary_y': False}, {'secondary_y': False}, {'secondary_y': False}],
                               [{'secondary_y': False}, {'secondary_y': False}, {'secondary_y': False}],
                               [{'secondary_y': False}, {'secondary_y': False}, {'secondary_y': False}]],
                        shared_xaxes=True, shared_yaxes=True,
                        vertical_spacing=0.01, horizontal_spacing=0,
                        row_heights=[0.775, 0.15, 0.025, 0.025, 0.025], column_widths=[0.8, 0.1, 0.1])
```

We add subplots as follows:

```
fig.add_trace(go.Scatter(x= ... row=1, col=1)
fig.add_trace(go.Scatter(x= ... row=1, col=2)
fig.add_trace(go.Scatter(x= ... row=2, col=1)
fig.add_trace(go.Scatter(x= ... row=3, col=1)
fig.add_trace(go.Scatter(x= ... row=4, col=1)
fig.add_trace(go.Scatter(x= ... row=5, col=1)
```

At position `row=1` `col=3` we place a table.

```
fig.add_trace(go.Table(header=dict(line=dict(color='red'),
                              fill=dict(color='red')),
                       cells=dict(values=[df.A, df.B])),
              row=1, col=3)
```

This all works fine. But when we add an `hline` or `vline` to the top left graph...

```
        fig.add_vline(x=42, line_width=1, line_dash='dot', line_color='rgba(255, 165, 0, 0.3)', row=1, col=1)
```

Plotly throws and error:

```
_plotly_utils.exceptions.PlotlyKeyError: Invalid property specified for object of type plotly.graph_objs.Table: 'xaxis'

Did you mean "cells"?
```

This happens regardless of line orientation (h or v), or if the lines are limited to a single row and col or spanning `all` cols.

Am I doing something wrong with my specs or layout, or could this be a bug?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not a developer of **plotly**. This does appear to be a bug in **plotly**.

- Adding the `Scatter()` traces, adding the the `go.Table()` to subplots then adding `vline()` fails
- Adding the `Scatter()` traces, adding the `vline()` then adding `Table()` subplot succeeds

Code below shows this in reproducible example,  changing where table is created means it succeeds or fails.  I'd suggest two ways forward

1. raise a bug / issue against plotly and wait for it to be fixed
2. use workaround to create contents in order that does work

```
import plotly.graph_objects as go
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from plotly.subplots import make_subplots

fig = make_subplots(rows=5, cols=3,
                        specs=[[{'secondary_y': True}, {'secondary_y': False}, {'type': 'table'}],
                               [{'secondary_y': False}, {'secondary_y': False}, {'secondary_y': False}],
                               [{'secondary_y': False}, {'secondary_y': False}, {'secondary_y': False}],
                               [{'secondary_y': False}, {'secondary_y': False}, {'secondary_y': False}],
                               [{'secondary_y': False}, {'secondary_y': False}, {'secondary_y': False}]],
                        shared_xaxes=True, shared_yaxes=True,
                        vertical_spacing=0.01, horizontal_spacing=0,
                        row_heights=[0.775, 0.15, 0.025, 0.025, 0.025], column_widths=[0.8, 0.1, 0.1])
for r in range(5):
    for c in range(3):
        if r==0 and c==2:
            if False:
                df=pd.DataFrame({"X":np.linspace(0,10,5), "Y":np.random.uniform(2,4,5)})
                fig.add_trace(go.Table(header={"values":df.columns}, cells={"values":df.T.values}), row=r+1, col=c+1)
            else:
                pass
        else:
            fig.add_trace(go.Scatter(x=np.linspace(0,50,20), y=np.random.uniform(1,5,29)), row=r+1, col=c+1)
            
fig.add_vline(x=42, line_width=1, line_dash='dot', line_color='rgba(255, 165, 0, 0.3)', row=1, col=1)

# create table after the vline has been added
df=pd.DataFrame({"X":np.linspace(0,10,5), "Y":np.random.uniform(2,4,5)})
fig.add_trace(go.Table(header={"values":df.columns}, cells={"values":df.T.values}), row=1, col=3)
```

Comment: thanks for thoroughly looking into this and proposing a workaround. I'll raise a bug and point to your post here to see if the team has any insights.

Comment: I wasted the last hour of my life looking for a solution to this problem. Thank you for providing this answer. 